# Assertion Error - Pyalgotrade

Tags: python, error-handling, pyalgotrade

I'm trying to use a technical indicator (Stochastic) but I'm getting an assertion error for this line :

```
self.__slow_stoch = stoch.StochasticOscillator(feed[instrument],self.__stoch, 3, self.__slow_d)
```

I'm using pyalgotrade to run a trading strategy in python. Any idea on how to fix this? I tried writting a Try/Exception for this error but with no luck...Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

```
from pyalgotrade import strategy
from pyalgotrade.tools import yahoofinance
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#Technical Analysis Libraries
from pyalgotrade import talibext
from pyalgotrade.talibext import indicator
from pyalgotrade.technical import ma
from pyalgotrade.technical import roc
from pyalgotrade.technical import rsi
from talib import MA_Type
from pyalgotrade.technical import stoch
import talib

class MyStrategy(strategy.BacktestingStrategy):
    def __init__(self, feed, instrument):
        super(MyStrategy, self).__init__(feed, 1000)
        self.__position = [] #None
        self.__instrument = instrument
        self.setUseAdjustedValues(True)
        self.__prices = feed[instrument].getPriceDataSeries()


        self.__stoch = stoch.StochasticOscillator(feed[instrument],5, dSMAPeriod=3, maxLen=1)
        self.__slow_d = ma.SMA(self.__stoch,3)
        self.__slow_stoch = stoch.StochasticOscillator(feed[instrument],self.__stoch, 3, self.__slow_d)


    def onEnterOk(self, position):
        execInfo = position.getEntryOrder().getExecutionInfo()
        self.info("BUY at $%.2f" % (execInfo.getPrice()))

    def onEnterCanceled(self, position):
        self.__position = None

    def onExitOk(self, position):
        execInfo = position.getExitOrder().getExecutionInfo()
        self.info("SELL at $%.2f" % (execInfo.getPrice()))
        self.__position = None

    def onExitCanceled(self, position):
        # If the exit was canceled, re-submit it.
        self.__position.exitMarket()

    def onBars(self, bars): #Verify data here

        bar = bars[self.__instrument]
        self.info("%s,%s" % (bar.getClose(),self.__slow_stoch[-1])  


def run_strategy(inst):
    # Load the yahoo feed from the CSV file

    feed = yahoofinance.build_feed([inst],2015,2016, ".") # feed = yahoofinance.build_feed([inst],2015,2016, ".")

    # Evaluate the strategy with the feed.
    myStrategy = MyStrategy(feed, inst)
    myStrategy.run()
    print "Final portfolio value: $%.2f" % myStrategy.getBroker().getEquity()


def main():
    instruments = ['ddd']
    for inst in instruments:
            run_strategy(inst)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Code:

```
    self.__stoch = stoch.StochasticOscillator(feed[instrument],5, dSMAPeriod=3, maxLen=1)
    slow_k = self.__stoch.getD()
    slow_d = ma.SMA(self.__stoch.getD(), 3)
    self.__slow_stoch = stoch.StochasticOscillator(feed[instrument],slow_k, dSMAPeriod=slow_d, maxLen=1)
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "algov1.py", line 224, in <module>
    main()
  File "algov1.py", line 220, in main
    run_strategy(inst)
  File "algov1.py", line 212, in run_strategy
    myStrategy = MyStrategy(feed, inst)
  File "algov1.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.__slow_stoch = stoch.StochasticOscillator(feed[instrument],slow_k, dSMAPeriod=slow_d, maxLen=1)
  File "C:\Users\JDOG\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyalgotrade\technical\stoch.py", line 90, in __init__
    technical.EventBasedFilter.__init__(self, barDataSeries, SOEventWindow(period, useAdjustedValues), maxLen)
  File "C:\Users\JDOG\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyalgotrade\technical\stoch.py", line 55, in __init__
    technical.EventWindow.__init__(self, period, dtype=object)
  File "C:\Users\JDOG\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyalgotrade\technical\__init__.py", line 41, in __init__
    assert(isinstance(windowSize, int))
AssertionError
```

Comment: Could you post complete assertion error traceback?

Comment: I updated the posting with the new code and the error.

Comment: The second parameter and third parameter must be integer type.

Comment: I tried doing int(slow_k) but still didint work. How do I make them integers if their values depend on self.__stoch?

Comment: slow_k is a sequence, not a single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is class definition of [StochasticOscillator](https://github.com/gbeced/pyalgotrade/blob/master/pyalgotrade/technical/stoch.py).

```
class StochasticOscillator(technical.EventBasedFilter):

    def __init__(self, barDataSeries, period, dSMAPeriod=3, useAdjustedValues=False, maxLen=dataseries.DEFAULT_MAX_LEN):
        assert dSMAPeriod > 1, "dSMAPeriod must be > 1"
        assert isinstance(barDataSeries, bards.BarDataSeries), \
            "barDataSeries must be a dataseries.bards.BarDataSeries instance"

        technical.EventBasedFilter.__init__(self, barDataSeries, SOEventWindow(period, useAdjustedValues), maxLen)
        self.__d = ma.SMA(self, dSMAPeriod, maxLen)
```

period and dSMAPeriod both are fixed integer.

When call StochasticOscillator(), Python will call `StochasticOscillator.__init__`, create and pass in `self` automatically, and you pass in left parameters with right order and type.

Update:

See code, dSMAPeriod is used to calculate D%, which is SMA of K%. When dSMAPeriod is 1, D% equals K%. Since you really want to set dSMAPeriod to 1, you can pass in dSMAPeriod=2, then use stoch itself.

Comment: sorry im a rookie. how do I incorporate that into my code?

class StochasticOscillator(technical.EventBasedFilter):
    def __init__(self, barDataSeries, period, dSMAPeriod=3, useAdjustedValues=False, maxLen=dataseries.DEFAULT_MAX_LEN):

Comment: That's class definition, you must pass right parameters following the `__init__` definition.

Comment: How would I incorporate the code I had in a way that allows me to get the slow stoch as I calculate it and so I can view it in the onbars function in self.info?

self.__stoch = stoch.StochasticOscillator(feed[instrument],5, dSMAPeriod=3, maxLen=1)
   
 slow_k = self.__stoch.getD()

    slow_d = ma.SMA(self.__stoch.getD(), 3)
    
self.__slow_stoch = stoch.StochasticOscillator(feed[instrument],slow_k, dSMAPeriod=slow_d, maxLen=1)

Comment: I don't understand your intent. You must use stoch like `stoch.StochasticOscillator(feed[instrument], 9, dSMAPeriod=3)`

Comment: I want to use the %D from the fast stochastic(self.__stoch) so I can find the slow stochastic...
In the "Code section" above i defined these:self.__stoch,slow_k,slow_d and  self.__slow_stoch. I'm trying to use the D% of self.__stoch to create the slow__stoch but I dont know how to do that using that class..

Comment: Dude, I got it! Thanks for all the help. Would you know how to make dSMAPeriod = 1, Currently as it the integer has to be greater than 1.